# How to extend function in another anonymous function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

All
I have following code:

```
(function($,undefined){
    function Abc(){
      function sayHello(){
          console.log("I am Abc");
      }
    }
})(jQuery);
```

And my question is, how can I add more methods to `Abc` or overwrite `sayHello`? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't. It's a local variable, private to that invocation of `Abc`. It cannot be overridden if `Abc` is written that way.

If you were actually making methods, perhaps like this:

```
function Abc() {
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("I am Abc");
    };
}
```

Then you could extend and override it like so:

```
function Cba() {
    Abc.apply(this, arguments);
    this.sayHello = function() {
        console.log("I am Cba");
    };
}
```

Comment: Thanks, icktoofay, got it. seems I have to find another way to extend jQuery FullCalendar.